# Quick sort with Insertion

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I need to repeat the quick insertion sort from Knuth's book, but it only sorts an array with 16 elements. I'm guessing the problem is due to argument passing on the stack. I need the code structure to remain like this

```cpp
void quickSort(vector<int>& arr) {
    int left, right;
    int M = 16;

    SortQ_stack* stack = nullptr;
    sortQ_push(&stack, 0, arr.size() - 1);

    while (stack != nullptr) {

        sortQ_pop(&stack, left, right);

        if (right - left + 1 <= M && right - left + 1 > 1) {
            //Q9 сортировка простыми вставками
            sortS(arr, left, right);
            return;
        }

        int K = arr[left];
        int i = left;
        int j = right + 1;



        while (true) {
            while (++i < j && arr[i] < K) {}
            while (i - 1 < --j && K < arr[j]) {}
            if (i < j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                if (left != j)
                {
                    arr[left] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = K;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (right - j > j - left) {
            sortQ_push(&stack, j + 1, right);
            right = j - 1;
        }
        else if (j - left > right - j) {
            sortQ_push(&stack, left, j - 1);
            left = j + 1;
        }
        else {
            if (left < right) {
                sortQ_push(&stack, j + 1, right);
                sortQ_push(&stack, left, j - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example original array:
384
356
316
535
438
148
613
973
563
486
467
235
627
668
652
470
196
884
337
659
703
422
287
580
446
860
895
515
685
795
546
969
151
763
505
489
811
118
462
375
505
830
510
132
498
163
503
595
947
741
254
651
163
441
231
509
302
127
924
887
822
471
856
873
234
362
363
946
380
726
321
785
556
732
818
955
795
321
550
742
962
704
394
126
146
526
535
348
553
460
236
375
831
993
249
966
355
513
912
635

Uncorrectly sorted array:

151 356 316 355 249 148 375 236 348 146 126 235 321 321 380 363 196 362 337 234 127 302 287 231 163 254 163 132 375 118 384 446 438 460 505 489 486 467 462 394 505 470 510 471 498 422 503 509 441 513 515 526 535 535 553 550 546 556 563 580 595 613 627 635 651 652 659 668 685 703 704 726 732 741 818 785 795 830 763 742 856 822 831 795 811 860 962 955 946 884 873 887 924 912 895 966 947 969 993 973

I need this to work correcly on 100, 500, 1000, 5000 arrays

My stack implementation

```cpp
struct SortQ_stack {
    int left;
    int right;
    SortQ_stack* next;
};

void sortQ_push(SortQ_stack** top, int l, int r) {
    SortQ_stack* new_node = new SortQ_stack();
    new_node->left = l;
    new_node->right = r;
    new_node->next = *top;
    *top = new_node;
}

void sortQ_pop(SortQ_stack** top, int& l, int& r) {
    if (*top == nullptr) {
        l = -1;
        r = -1;
        return;
    }
    l = (*top)->left;
    r = (*top)->right;
    SortQ_stack* temp = *top;
    *top = (*top)->next;
    delete temp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `return` after `sortS`?  That seems like it can't possibly accomplish much.  Surely you want to continue the loop and sort the other chunks.

Comment: *"Knuth's book"*: [which one?](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/books.jpg)

Comment: book should be called "D. Knuth. The art of computer programming. Sorting and searching"

i've also found similiar description of algorithm
http://math.utoledo.edu/~codenth/Fall_14/4380/Notes/quicksort.pdf

Comment: i've changed to continue after sortS but it didnt quit help. it still sort's the same

Comment: @smallshorty *I need this to work correcly on 100, 500, 1000, 5000 arrays* -- You need it to work for arrays of 20 and 30 also.  I suggest you start with a smaller amount, such as 20 items.  It your sort cannot handle 20 elements, it isn't going to work for 100 or higher elements.  Also, the smaller number of elements will make the code easier to debug.

Comment: *I need the code structure to remain like this* -- What is `SortQ_stack`?  For anyone to test your code, we need a [mcve].

Comment: Of Knuth's great works, I'm [kinda partial to this one.](https://silezukuk.tumblr.com/post/616657913)

Comment: I tried to write the stack myself so that the teacher could see how everything works. but he refuses to understand what is in my stack and what is in <stack>.
You can implement any other stack and it will be even better

Comment: i've edit the question and added my stack implementation

Comment: What is `sortS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- You shouldn't return after having called `sortS`, as there might be more ranges to sort on the stack.
- As you start each iteration with a pop from the stack, it makes no sense to end the loop's iteration by setting `left` or `right` (as you do in the `if... else if` blocks). These values are immediately overwritten by what you pop from the stack. However, looking at how you decide to put the largest partition on the stack, and want to continue with the remaining partition (avoiding as much as possible to use the stack), I think you wanted to avoid stacking two partitions only to pop one of them immediately. This could be seen as a waste of stack space. But if that is the case, you should actually *not* pop a partition from the stack at the start of the loop, but only do that when you have dealt with a partition that cannot be split anymore. This is for example the case when you have called `sortS`: at that point the current partition is completely sorted and needs no more subdivisions. That's the moment to pop a next partition from the stack.
- I didn't understand why at the end of the loop you have a special treatment for the case where the two partitions are equal in size. In light of the above point, you should never have to push *two* partitions on the stack (although that would be the way to do it if you start the iteration with a pop, but you have to make up your mind which way to go).

Not a problem, but:

- The second part of the condition `if (right - left + 1 <= M && right - left + 1 > 1)` could be dropped if you make sure your insertion sort `sortS` will work well with `left`/`right` arguments that violate this second condition.
- As to the testing your quicksort code, I would suggest to reduce the size of the input, and to set `M` to 2: the insertion sort part should not get a big role in such tests.

Here is the correction of your code:

```
void quickSort(vector<int>& arr) {
    int left = 0, right = arr.size() - 1; // Don't use stack yet
    // Set M to a low value until you are certain quickSort works perfectly
    int M = 2;  
    
    // Start with an empty stack to save stack space
    SortQ_stack* stack = nullptr; 
    // As a consequence the loop condition involves left/right
    while (right > left || stack) { 
        if (right <= left) { // Only pop when nothing to sort in current range
            sortQ_pop(&stack, left, right);
        }
 
        if (right - left + 1 <= M) {  // Simplified condition
            //Q9 Sorting with simple inserts
            sortS(arr, left, right);
            left = right; // Trigger a pop in next iteration
            continue; // Don't return!!
        }

        int K = arr[left];
        int i = left;
        int j = right + 1;
        while (true) {
            while (++i < j && arr[i] < K) {}
            while (i - 1 < --j && K < arr[j]) {}
            if (i < j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                if (left != j)
                {
                    arr[left] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = K;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
       if (right - j > j - left) {
            if (right > j + 1) { // Only push windows larger than 1
                sortQ_push(&stack, j + 1, right);
            }
            right = j - 1;
        }
        else { // There should be no other cases besides this one
            if (j - 1 > left) { // Only push windows larger than 1
                sortQ_push(&stack, left, j - 1);
            }
            left = j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```